# Annotation Functionality in barteksc AndroidPdfViewer library

Tags: android, pdfium

Currently i am working on app where i need to add search functionality in PDF viewer.

For loading pdf i am using barteksc library.
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I want to Know following :-

1)In existence library what is use of **enableAnnotationRendering**  method.

2)How can i add search and annotation functionality in existence library.

Here is the code that currently i am using

```
 pdfView.fromFile(uri)
                .defaultPage(0)                   
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)                 
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .onPageError(this)
                .spacing(10)
                .onDraw(new OnDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {

                        // set a margin, otherwise depending on device resolution, border is not displayed (falls outside the component)
                        final float MARGIN = 1f;
                        // compute coordinates
                        float xLeft = (-1f * displayedPage * pageWidth) + MARGIN;
                        float xRight = (-1f * displayedPage * pageWidth) + pageWidth - MARGIN;
                        float yGlobalTop = MARGIN;
                        float yGlobalBottom = ((float) pdfView.getPageCount() * pageHeight) - MARGIN;
                        float yTop = (displayedPage * pageHeight) + MARGIN;
                        float yBottom = ((displayedPage + 1f) * pageHeight) - MARGIN;
                        // left vertical border
                        canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yGlobalTop, xLeft,  yGlobalBottom, drawPaint);
                        // right vertical border
                        canvas.drawLine(xRight,  yGlobalTop, xRight,  yGlobalBottom, drawPaint);
                        // top origin horizontal border
                        canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yGlobalTop, xRight,  yGlobalTop, drawPaint);
                        // bottom horizontal border up to current page - 2
                        for (int loopPage = 0; loopPage < (displayedPage - 1) && loopPage < pdfView.getPageCount(); loopPage++) {
                            float yLoopEnd = ((loopPage + 1f) * pageHeight) - MARGIN;
                            canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yLoopEnd, xRight,  yLoopEnd, drawPaint);
                        }
                        // top and bottom horizontal borders for current page
                        // not in the loop to have correct borders when display page fills the screen
                        canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yTop, xRight,  yTop, drawPaint);
                        canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yBottom, xRight,  yBottom, drawPaint);
                        // bottom horizontal border up to last page
                        for (int loopPage = displayedPage + 1; loopPage < pdfView.getPageCount(); loopPage++) {
                            float yLoopEnd = ((loopPage + 1f) * pageHeight) - MARGIN;
                            canvas.drawLine(xLeft,  yLoopEnd, xRight,  yLoopEnd, drawPaint);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .onDrawAll(new OnDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                        Log.e("onDrawAll",pageWidth+":"+pageHeight+":"+displayedPage);
                    }
                })
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load();
```

Comment: I don't know the answer how to achieve that...but for only the reference i used this lib and this gives the feature exactly what you want to use 
https://github.com/foobnix/LibreraReader

Comment: @Vivek Patel
i also want text search and highlight it - functionality in this library.
If you or any one using this functionality then please share the code
I need it.

Comment: @SujeetKumar ,this functionality cannot be achieved using this library because pdf which is loaded is converted to Image Files. For text search and highlighting i used some other login .

Comment: @VivekPatel Thanks for reply man.
So for text search in pdf and highlight it which library i have to use any idea plz share it.